# Erasing DrawReversibleFrame from screen

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble with removing DrawReversibleFrame from the screen. Docs say to enter the function twice to remove it but it seems like it does not work with my logic layout.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Point? _start;
    private Rectangle _previousBounds;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _start = e.Location;
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_start.HasValue)
        {
            ReverseFrame();
            DrawFrame(e.Location);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ReverseFrame();
        _start = null;
    }

    private void ReverseFrame()
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(_previousBounds, Color.Red, FrameStyle.Dashed);

    }
    private void DrawFrame(Point end)
    {
        ReverseFrame();

        var size = new Size(end.X - _start.Value.X, end.Y - _start.Value.Y);
        _previousBounds = new Rectangle(_start.Value, size);
        _previousBounds = RectangleToScreen(_previousBounds);
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(_previousBounds, Color.Red, FrameStyle.Dashed);
    }
}
}
```

This is my result when I drag my mouse on the form. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQGDO.jpg

The pesudo code should work like this which I feel like I am doing.

MouseDown:

Draw rectangle.

Save rectangle bounds.

--

MouseMove (w/ left button down):

Redraw previous rectangle to erase.

Calculate next rectangle.

Draw next rectangle.

Save rectangle bounds.

Rinse/Repeat (indefinitely)

--

MouseUp:

Redraw last rectangle to erase.

Comment: You'll have to remember that the *first* call to ReverseFrame() is invalid.  Since there isn't anything to reverse yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe(v=vs.110).aspx)

MouseUp handler in the example is point of interest.

```
 private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the MouseUp event occurs, the user is not dragging.
            isDrag = false;

            // Draw the rectangle to be evaluated. Set a dashed frame style 
            // using the FrameStyle enumeration.
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(theRectangle, this.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);

            // Find out which controls intersect the rectangle and 
            // change their color. The method uses the RectangleToScreen  
            // method to convert the Control's client coordinates 
            // to screen coordinates.
            Rectangle controlRectangle;
            for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                controlRectangle = Controls[i].RectangleToScreen(Controls[i].ClientRectangle);
                if (controlRectangle.IntersectsWith(theRectangle))
                {
                    Controls[i].BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
                }
            }

            // Reset the rectangle.
            theRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Specifically, I put following line under comment when tested it and got the same result as yours.

```
// ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(theRectangle, this.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
```

**Update**

I tested your code. I think your rectangle _previousBounds is not getting drawn for the second time.

Comment: I tried the microsoft example and it works a bit better. The problem I have now it flickers every frame I move it.